# Android Studio highlight problems in code

Tags: android, android-studio

So I've just moved a bunch of code from another project to a new project and I have a bunch of errors (missing classes, methods, resources, etc)

As I was copy-pasting the new classes in the new project it would automatically analyze the class and highlight the problems with red.

I closed Android Studio and now after reopening it, it doesn't show the errors anymore. If I try to clean or rebuild the project it just shows the first problem it finds and highlights that, nothing else.

If I go in a specific file with problems it does indeed highlight the issues, but I'd like a solution for all the files in the project.

How can I make it scan the entire project and highlight ALL the problem areas/methods/classes/resources/etc ? I'd like to have an "overview" of the problematic classes/packages/etc.

Comment: Right click in the project and select Analyze Code

Comment: Already did an Inspect Code, but it won't highlight the issues, it will just give me a list of things ...

Comment: I think that I had the same problem. It's android studio.. Try to recreate your project and move all files separately one by one into the new project. That helped me..